# How to test if the browser supports the native placeholder attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, testing, placeholder

I'm trying to write a simple placeholder jQuery plugin for a site of mine but of course I only want to fire the function if the native placeholder attribute isn't supported…

**How can I use jQuery to test for native support of the placeholder attribute?**

Comment: Thanks for the link. Excellent resource.

Comment: The link provided by @hellvinz is sadly now 410 gone. Here is an updated mirror: http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html#input-placeholder

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can add to [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) quite easily by inserting this at the top of the Javascript you've written:

```
jQuery.support.placeholder = (function(){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in i;
})();
```

You can then use either `$.support.placeholder` or `jQuery.support.placeholder` anywhere in your code.

NB This code adapted from [diveintohtml5](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/detect.html#input-placeholder), the link provided by hellvinz above.

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. PS: Thanks for the link, great resource. *Bookmarked!*

Comment: Thank hellvinz, not me, for the link!  What's more, it would be trivial to create a plugin that imports all Modernizr tests to `$.support`.  A quick test reveals that it would be a 11kb file once minified.

Comment: even if all i want to test for is form functionality?

Comment: No, that's for the whole library.  I've rewritten the diveintohtml5.org HTML5 form code as a plugin to extend `$.support`.  It's at http://pastebin.com/NVs09xzX at the moment and I'll put it on the jQuery site as a plugin soon.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! That little plugin is exactly what I needed. Do you mind if I include it in my jquery plugin that I'm writing at the moment?

Comment: I like the solution (if you are not using Modernizr), but the `'placeholder' in i` is actualy a little bit more performance heavy to perform than `i.placeholder !== undefined` due to the fact that the script has to map ALL the objects attributes before the check is performed. Not a big change, but everything counts and generally the `[some att] in [some object]` should be avoided if possible for the reason mentioned.

Comment: Note that this technique obviously works without jQuery as well.

Comment: Can't this be shortened to `$.support.placeholder = document.createElement('input').placeholder !== undefined;`?

Comment: Be aware that jQuery says about `$.support`: `Intended for jQuery's internal use; specific properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally to improve page startup performance.` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/

Answer (score 15):

Use the Modernizr library, which you can find here: http://www.modernizr.com/

And then do this:

```
if (Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
  // your placeholder text should already be visible!
} else {
  // no placeholder support :(
  // fall back to a scripted solution
}
```

Modernizr is really handy for testing the browser's support for almost all HTML5 functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already using Modernizr in my document however for this plugin to work on all sites I don't want to rely on any external libraries such as Modernizr other than jQuery of course. On my current page that I am building this indeed works great, but just for general compatibility I'd prefer something not reliant on Modernizr.

Answer (score 4):

I like having such a simple class ...

```
var Browser = {
  Can: {
    Placeholder: function () {
      return 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input'); 
    }
  }
}
```

... so you can easily check if your browser supports the placeholder attribute.

```
if (Browser.Can.Placeholder()) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `placeholder` property exists on INPUT DOM objects in all browsers regardless whether or not the placeholder attribute has been defined on the HTML INPUT element.

The correct way is:

```
var Modernizr = {};
// Create the input element for various Web Forms feature tests.
var inputElem = document.createElement('input'), attrs = {};    
Modernizr.input = (function(props) {
    for(var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++) {
        attrs[props[i]] = props[i] in inputElem;
    }
    return attrs;
})('autocomplete autofocus list placeholder max min multiple pattern required step'.split(' '));

if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    // Do something.
}
```