# HTML Placeholder browser compatibility

Tags: html, dom, browser, placeholder

What browsers support the placeholder html tag for text inputs? Does Internet Explorer support it? (I have a JavaScript placeholder that I can use for the browsers that do not support it.)

`<input type=TEXT placeholder="placeholder here" />`

Comment: Fair question! My guess is that IE doesn't support it at all, it being a HTML 5 attribute. But I'm too lazy to research it, too. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is currently supported by all major browsers except IE 9 and earlier and Opera mini.

For updates, look at the [w3schools-specs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) Or even better, view this [overview](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder).

Comment: As from version 3.7 Firefox supports this too. Opera from version 11 and Iphone from version 4.0. Just so you know.

Comment: Check the support for HTML placeholder on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: IE 10 supports it, I can see the placeholder text in IE 10 :) so good news from IE! unbelievable :D

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is sane and good, do not use w3schools. For current browser support, caniuse is a good resource: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Comment: w3school is NOT a good source of info anymore (some say it used to be), see [www.w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 18):

For anyone interested, this is the jQuery Fallback that I use 
I use it with jQuery Validation Engine.
*Replace FORMCLASS with the class of your form.*

```
<!-- IF IE - use Placeholder Fallback -->
<!--[if lt IE 10 ]>
<script>
  $(".FORMCLASS").find('[placeholder]').each(function(){ 
    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    $(this).focus(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('placeholder')==$(this).val()) {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: as alternative to [if lt IE 10 ] in HTML
something like

jQuery.support.placeholder = (function(){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in i;
})();

can be used. Taken from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937818/how-to-test-if-the-browser-supports-the-native-placeholder-attribute)

Comment: There is a problem if user someway skips the focus, e.g. just clicks "submit", then the placeholder is passed as field value.

Comment: Note this will not display the placeholder text for password fields.

Comment: this is introduced in html5.  For older browsers, you can use javascript to fake it by prefilling and removing text when it's clicked on if it matches the hint text and putting the hint text back if you empty the box.

Answer (score 17):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547102.aspx), IE 10 supports it. (You can [test it here](http://jsbin.com/ibehew/edit#preview))

I fix the problem this -probably the most easiest- way:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>email:<![endif]-->
<input placeholder='email' type='text' name='email'>
```

Comment: IE 10 supports it. Just Tested.

Comment: I like this solution - no JS to worry about.

Comment: Definitely easiest solution here

Answer (score 10):

Firefox also supports it since 4.0

Answer (score 8):

IE is not supporting placeholders

I feel this code better and it works in all major browsers

```
<input id="example-email" type="text" value="Email Address" onfocus="if(this.value === 'Email Address') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value === '') this.value = 'Email Address';" name="example-email">
```

Comment: I do not think your code is better. That's the old way. I know it works. But actually we do not need this javascript for most of the browsers. So we should use the placeholder attribute. And if we cannnot or dont't want to forget the IE then we have to provide an explicit solution for IE only.

Answer (score 6):

Question may have been answered a few years ago, but I found it today doing a search.

Since a good reference and pics were not provided before, I am updating this question with both.

[HTML5  placeholder Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) basically says:

> The placeholder attribute is supported in all major browsers, except Internet Explorer.

**FYI:** This includes IE9.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possibly as it's w3schools, it does have some incorrect information. That said, in this case it has exactly what I want, so upvote!

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking for a HTML5-placeholder alike solution for non-supported browsers here is a good article about it:

http://www.viget.com/inspire/a-better-jquery-in-field-label-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

*Placeholders* are fully supported by:

- FF 4+
- Chrome 4+
- Safari 5+
- Opera 11.6+
- IE 10+

Source: **[Can I use input placeholder attribute?](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)**

Answer (score 2):

For those who want the simplest solution, use the built-in features!

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" placeholder="Email Address" onfocus="if(this.value==this.placeholder) this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.placeholder">
```

Tested in chrome and IE8 :)

Note: I use this with more javascript to validate the input and give feedback inside the field itself by changing the value and placeholder at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old question. My suggestion is to use Modernizr for detecting placeholder support! https://modernizr.com/