# get default value of input after change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how it is possible to retrieve the default value of an input field after `.val()` was changed. My markup are different text-inputs with classes `.large` and `.medium` and I have a default text value in every field.

What I want to do is, when the user `focusin` the field the default value disappears. When `focusout` the field, the default value comes back. Now when the user already typed something in, the field keeps the typed in value even on `focusout` BUT what I can't get to work is, if the user deletes its typed in text and focusses out the default value should appear again.

My code is:

```
        var $inputs = $('.large, .medium');
        var allowSaveVal = true;    

        $inputs.on('focusin', this, function() { 
             saveVal = $(this).val();
             if (allowSaveVal) $(this).val('');
        });

        $inputs.on('keydown', this, function() {
            allowSaveVal = false;
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
        });

        $inputs.on('focusout', this, function() { 
            if($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(saveVal);
            if (allowSaveVal) $(this).val(saveVal);
        });
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to code this, just make use the `placeholder` attribute. Example: `<input type="text" placeholder="default text">`

Comment: @Hatsjoem how simple it is, I didn't know that attribute. Can you make it as answer?

Comment: How simple it can be, right? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to code this, just make use the `placeholder` attribute.

Example:

`<input type="text" placeholder="default text">`

Comment: just make sure your audience uses browsers where the `placeholder` attribute is supported, have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004087/html-placeholder-browser-compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004087/html-placeholder-browser-compatibility)

Comment: ...and nonetheless, this will only work if the user hasn't typed in anything yet into the field, as noted by @KeremZaman in their answer...

Comment: @webeno but the answer isn't available anymore. It was a solution with data-attributes, but I can't see it, would be nice to know! edit: ah no, it was someone else!

Comment: i still see it, it says at the end: 'If the user enters a value into the input and focusout, the value doesn't disappear.'

Comment: @webeno yeah sorry my fault, didn't refresh! thanks for the infos!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "placeholder" in your html codes instead of js or jquery.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="yourdefaultvalue" />
```

If the user enters a value into the input and focusout, the value doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Save the value in a variable in your js code before you'd change anything and you'll be able to call it later.

```
var largeInit = $('.large').val();
var mediumInit = $('.medium').val();
```

Comment: the problem is, since there are a few inputs but only 2 classes I don't know how to select each value and later assign it to the correct one.

Comment: no, I might explained myself a bit bad but I have more inputs than two! But only 2 classes so I can't save each as one var.

Comment: why don't you id your inputs?

Comment: @the inputs are generated dynamically by a plugin. thought it isn't needed. placeholder does a good job tho!

Comment: just make sure your audience uses browsers where the `placeholder` attribute is supported, have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004087/html-placeholder-browser-compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004087/html-placeholder-browser-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

If i completely understand your question  then you can do that with place-holder attribute for that html element

try :

```
<input type='text' placeholder='This your default value' />
```

If this helps dont forget to accept answer.