# Bind live each function with a click event?

Tags: jquery, bind, live, placeholder

I have searched and found multiple answers simply stating to wrap my function in a click handler, although I want it to run on page load, or once my javascript has finished inserting all the html.

I have a whole page that's dynamically created. I'm using this snippet to fix Placeholders for IE. It does work, although not with live created elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    // Placeholder Fix for IE < 9    
    $("[placeholder]").each(function() {        
        var val = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        if ( this.value === "" ) {
            this.value = val;
        }
        $(this).focus(function() {
            if ( this.value == val ) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            if ( $.trim(this.value) === "" ) {
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
    });
    // Clear default placeholder values on form submit
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find("[placeholder]").each(function() {
            if ( this.value == $(this).attr("placeholder") ) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm adding in form elements with js, example:

```
$('body').append('<input type="text" placeholder="placeholdertext" />');
```

Can someone advise how to fix this problem?

Shannon

Comment: When you say dynamically created.. do you mean by server or js?  If the target elements are not yet in the dom when the for loop runs it wont obviously work.  If you're dynamically adding text inputs in JS, use `$(<target that already exists in dom>).on('focus','<target inputs>', function(e) {   /* stuff here */ });`

Comment: whenever you add new elements with `placeholder` attribute,you need to run your code for those new elements. Provide sample code that adds new elements

Comment: do the same for blur, and set the control val up when it's created.  `on` is equiv to `live`

Comment: also note that you aren't just running this code for IE...you are running it for all browsers. Use feature detection to run it only on browsers that don't support `placeholder`. There are numerous plugins already developed for doing this

Comment: This script is in it's on js file, wrapped in a html if statement, it's only included in IE, yes I'm including form elements with javascript, and I do NOT want to bind this function with an event like blur, or focus because I want the script run before the user is playing with any form fields. As I mentioned, it replaces the placeholder attribute, so I obviously don't want it to build it when a user clicks on the field. Thankyou!

Comment: define `live created elements` and provide some sample code

Comment: I think it kind of explains it self, but as an example, I've edit my post.

Comment: see this post on how to use `$.support` instead of IE conditional, then you have to apply your function to any newly added elements if not supported, as well as calling it on page load  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937818/how-to-test-if-the-browser-supports-the-native-placeholder-attribute. Again, numerous plugins have been written for this... try one of those

Comment: I much prefer using conditionals, that also has nothing to do with this post, using the $.support will be embedded in the js file, it's also not read at all if it's not matched with IE conditionals, the whole file however would be read on every browser if I was to use the support function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

The on() function applies handlers to all elements that fit the selector on the page, not just that specific element (like .focus and .blur)
More Info Here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(this).on("focus", function() {
            if ( this.value == val ) {
                this.value = "";
            }
        }).on("blur", (function() {
            if ( $.trim(this.value) === "" ) {
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: No, I was looking for a solution to run the above function without an event so that it's invoked on page load.