# Detect if the HTML5 `required` attribute is enforced

Tags: html, forms

Is there an easy way to test if the HTML5 `required` attribute is actually enforced by a browser when submitting a form? i.e. the form can't be submitted if a required field has not been filled in.

I'd rather not add modernizr just for that, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937924/117704 does not work for Safari: Safari does not prevent the form submission when a required field , and still `document.createElement('input').required` is not `undefined` in Safari.

I want to implement a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319587/117704 but enable it only for browsers not enforcing the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the checkValidity() function exists:

```
function hasFormValidation() {

    return (typeof document.createElement( 'input' ).checkValidity == 'function');

};
```

Call it like this:

```
if( hasFormValidation() ) {
    // Form Validation supported
};
```

Comment: Reference from the HTML Standard for completion: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidity. Nice solution.

Comment: it returns true for Safari, even though Safari does not prevent form submission when a required field is missing

Comment: finally had to use a browser detection instead of a feature detection